# Best and Worst case time complexity and represent it in asymptotic notation for the following function

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

```
function(A[], n):
   swapped = true, start = 0, end = n-l1
   while swapped == true
      swapped = false
      for i = start to end-1
         if Af[i] > A[iti1]
            swap(A[i], A[iti]}
            swapped = true
      if swapped == false
         break
      end = end-1
      swapped = false
      for i = end-1 down to start
         if A[f[i] > A[it1]
            swap(A[i], A[iti]}
            swapped = true
      if swapped == false
         break
      start = start+l1;
```

Comment: Please indent your algorithm, fix typos and remove tags: `C` and `asymmetric`.

Comment: I guess this is cocktail shaker sort, and if so, the corresponding wikipedia page has the answers.

Answer (score 0):

- For **best case** the time complexity is **O(n**)
- For **worst case** the time complexity is **O(n*n)**

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code has typos, as if you had used OCR to get the text...

I suppose it should be:

```
function(A[], n):
   swapped = true, start = 0, end = n-1
   while swapped == true
      swapped = false
      for i = start to end-1
         if A[i] > A[i+1]
            swap(A[i], A[i+1])
            swapped = true
      if swapped == false
         break
      end = end-1
      swapped = false
      for i = end-1 down to start
         if A[i] > A[i+1]
            swap(A[i], A[i+i])
            swapped = true
      if swapped == false
         break
      start = start+1;
```

It implements [shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort), with complexity **O(n)** for the best case (sorted array) and **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** for the worst case (reverse sorted array).